# How can I create socket.io context and use functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have backend chat which is written by socket.io, there is an event name is new-message. I want to connect my frontend to this socket.io. But when I create context and create function inside it, like useNewMessage() and want to use this function on my another page it returns null. I have checked connection inside useNewMessage() function, socket connection seems working smoothly and I can log it. But when I send data via API to socket io and want to get it, I just get null.

```
import { composeWithDevToolsLogOnlyInProduction } from "@redux-devtools/extension";
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

const SocketContext = createContext();

export const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedAccessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    const newSocket = io("https://localhost:3000", {
      extraHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${storedAccessToken}`,
      },
    });

    newSocket.on("connect", () => {
      setSocket(newSocket);
    });

    // Clean up the Socket.io connection on component unmount
    return () => {
      newSocket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket && socket.connected) {
      console.log("Socket connection ID:", socket.id);
    }
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      {socket ? children : null}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSocket = () => {
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  if (!socket) {
    throw new Error(
      "Socket connection not available. Make sure to wrap your component with SocketProvider."
    );
  }

  return socket;
};

export const useNewMessage = () => {
  const socket = useSocket();
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNewMessage = (message) => {
      setNewMessage(message);
    };

    socket.on("new-message", handleNewMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off("new-message", handleNewMessage);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return newMessage;
};
```

When I change, edit or save my context it starts listen and I can get new-messages with using useNewMessage function. But after refresh page it again returns null. How can I solve this problem ?